# EAR eclipse facet: Some jars go to "\Modules\Binary" some others go to "\Utility Jars"?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, manifest, ear

On a EAR project, Eclipse creates a "Binary" folder with several jars inside!
Several jars are correctly placed in the "Utility Jars" folder.
Why my jars are not all included in the "Utility Jars" folder?

here is a sreenshot of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU0Zs.png

Whey I run my code to try to genere a pdf, the application silently doesn't do anything and I presume it's because the iText.jar is not in the class path or something.

What do you think? Can you help me with this?
Thanks